# Exchanging a type parameter's upper bound for an evidence parameter

Tags: scala, implicit, type-parameter

I want to relax the constraints on a trait's type parameter and instead impose them on a method in the form of an evidence parameter. Given some skeletal setup:

```
trait State[Repr]
object Observer {
  def apply[Repr <: State[Repr]](reader: Reader[Repr]): Observer[Repr] = 
    new Observer[Repr] {}
}
trait Observer[A]
trait Reader  [A]
```

This works:

```
trait StateX[Repr <: StateX[Repr]] extends State[Repr] { 
  protected def reader: Reader[Repr]
  def observe: Observer[Repr] = Observer(reader)
}
```

And this doesn't:

```
trait StateY[Repr] extends State[Repr] { 
  protected def reader: Reader[Repr]
  def observe(implicit ev: Repr <:< State[Repr]): Observer[Repr] = Observer(reader)
}
```

With message `"inferred type arguments [Repr] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [Repr <: State[Repr]]"`. Since the evidence `ev` suggests this conformation, I wonder how `StateY` can be fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that even though evidence of the form `A <:< B` implies that a value of type `A` can be converted to a value of type `B` it doesn't imply `A <: B` ... indeed, the main reason for using a type constraint or a view bound rather than an ordinary type bound is precisely because such a subtype relationship doesn't hold.

Consequently the constraint in `StateY`, `Repr <:< State[Repr]`, isn't sufficient to satisfy the bound `Repr <: State[Repr]` on `Observer`'s `apply` method. Given that you want to relax the constraint on `StateX`'s type parameter your only option is to weaken the constraint on the `apply` method's type parameter correspondingly. That gets you something like the following using a view bound instead of an ordinary type bound,

```
object Observer {
  def apply[Repr <% State[Repr]](reader : Reader[Repr]) : Observer[Repr] =
    new Observer[Repr] {}
}
```

or alternatively,

```
object Observer {
  def apply[Repr](reader : Reader[Repr])
                 (implicit ev : Repr <:< State[Repr]) : Observer[Repr] =
    new Observer[Repr] {}
}
```

if you'd rather use constraints throughout.

Answer (score 5):

The evidence suggests that a `Repr` can be converted to `State[Repr]`. It says nothing about what can be done with a Reader[Repr].

There is no general method (independant of T) to convert T[A] to T[B] given an A => B. That might be possible for a covariant T, but there is no  such thing in the language.